# Bash If statement adding blank lines to end of document

Tags: bash

I have a simple script which checks if a file exists, it works fine but seems like every time It executes, adds a new blank line to the end of the document

```
if [[ -f /usr/local/sbin/.env ]]; 
then
        :
else
        touch /usr/local/sbin/.env

fi
```

It should only check if the file exists, If it does, do nothing => `:` else create it:

Comment: Nothing here adds a blank line to anything. It must be something else doing it.

Comment: Unless you care greatly about the modification time of the file, I would just touch it unconditionally.

Comment: is it possible someone has used `:` as an alias or function name?

Answer (score 1):

just check with negation

```
if [[ ! -f /usr/local/sbin/.env ]]; 
    then
            touch /usr/local/sbin/.env
    fi
```

Comment: That was it @Taron Qalashyan

Comment: This is simpler, but I don't see how it could make a difference.

Comment: It does not resolve the blank line adding issue, it just helps to avoid having blank if statement.